# DriverManager. not lsting the right option

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I have tried with both mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar file. The DriverManager. -> does not show the right options as it should show(url,user,password), but for me it shows(arg0,arg1,arg2) and due to this it is not connecting to DB because of the option selected.

Attaching Snapshots for both what it should show and what it is showing for me.

[image]

Comment: That has nothing to do with the JDBC driver you installed, as `DriverManager` is part of Java itself. This would suggest that either you haven't installed the sources with Java, or that maybe your Eclipse version doesn't fully support Java 10 and has trouble locating its sources.

Comment: `arg0,arg1,arg2` are just names of parameter, which is equivalent to `url,user,password`, what else do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your inputs was very helpful in getting to know various things.

However I got the issue resolved I had to do just a small change as below:

Before:
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rrr","root","root")

After:
"jdbc:mysql://**127.0.0.1**:3306/rrr","root","root")

The DNS name was not getting resolved to an IP I had to give the IP.

Thanks,
Vishwas